# SwiftUI - Horizontal ScrollView becomes Vertically scrollable

Tags: swiftui, scrollview

I have a problem with SwiftUI's ScrollView. If you run the app on a smaller screen (iPhone SE 1st gen for example), the ScrollView (horizontal) goes out of the screen because it doesn't fit its height on it. Therefore it becomes scrollable vertically also. I have an outer scroll view (vertical) therefore I don't want the inner ScrollView to be able to scroll vertically. Any ideas on how can I fix this?

```
ScrollView(.vertical) {  // <------ Outher one
   Text("Welcome")

   ScrollView(.horizontal) { // <------ Inner one (if it doesnt fit on screen it becomes vertically scrollable
      HStack {
        Content...
      }
   }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Not reproducible with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1. Would you provide minimal standalone reproducible example?

Comment: Sure, in a bit, I can't right now, I'm very sorry. And thanks for taking the time